# Is it true that $f = 0$ identically on $X\ $?

Tags: measure-theory, continuity, topological-groups, haar-measure

> Let $(X,\mathcal A, \mu)$ be a measure space where $X$ is topological space and $\mu$ is a Borel measure on  $\mathcal A.$ Let $f : X \longrightarrow \mathbb C$ be a continuous function which is zero $\mu$ a.e. Does it necessarily imply that $f = 0$ identically on $X\ $?

If $X$ is a topological group and $\mu$ is a Haar measure on the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$ then I know that it is true. What about any arbitrary topological space $X\ $? Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not always! Take $X = \{a, b, c\}$ with the discrete topology, and let $\mu$ be the measure $\mu(\{a\}) = 1$ and $\mu(\{b, c\}) = 0$ (this uniquely determines a measure on the power set of $X$). Then $f(a) = 0, f(b) = f(c) = 17$ is a counterexample to the statement. In general, measures can be very wild.

Comment: Is there any counter-example for topological groups and Borel measure?

Comment: @Fanatics Yes, take any Dirac measure on your favorite topological group, and the same trick will work.

Comment: You can even take $\mu \equiv 0$, then every continuous function vanishes a.e.